# How to calling text in public void PassValue(string) to private void Form1_Load()

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I need some help. 
There is a text "Hello" `(strvalue = "Hello")` in

```
public void PassValue(string strValue)
```

Why I can't use this text in this method below?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Error will occur:

> "The name 'strValue' does not exist in the current content".

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  label1.text = strValue;
  //strValue does not exist
}

 public void PassValue(string strValue )
{

   strValue = "Hello"; 
}
```

Expected result that I looking for is strValue can be read in `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This doesn't look like the right way to do it. Why aren't you taking this value as a constructor parameter? Anyhow, `strValue` is scoped to the body of `PassValue`, so `Form1_Load` can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can store it as a member variable and then set it when required:

```
private string m_StrValue;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  label1.text = m_StrValue;
}

public void PassValue(string strValue )
{

  m_StrValue = strValue;
}
```